# reduce firing events

Tags: jquery, request, slider, onchange

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 1800,
    min: 600,
    max: 20000,
    step: 10,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
       $("#amount").val(ui.value + " m³/h").change();
    }
 }
```

`$('#amount').change()`  retrieves data from a ajax request.

The data comes from a database so it takes a second to get it.When sliding the slidebar the amount should increase/decrese but the ajax request should trigerd once a second.

The change function handles multiple input types

Comment: What's the problem and where is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var timer;
clearTimeout(timer);
var old_val = $("#amount").val();
timer = setTimeout(function(){
    if (old_val == $("#amount").val())
    {
        ajaxRequest();
    }
}, 1000);
```